# Decrease the size of the background of a text box using bootstrap carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using Bootstrap 4.0 and the carousel class. I have a caption for each image that is part of the carousel, and would like to decrease the width of the background of the caption since it is wider than the text. (see yellow arrows below)[image: Picture of oversizes background] I have used different bootstrap classes such as d-md-flex, but it moves the entire text box to the left.

How can I decrease the width of the background?  The text is not dynamic, so although it would be preferable to have a flex option, I can use a fixed or maximum width. It needs to be centered though.

Thanks!

```
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/t/flowers.svg" alt="Creativity">
  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-dark">
    <h1 style="background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250,0.5);">Everyday Creativity</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so we need to align text to center and width to be only as per the width of the content...

**working snippet** below:

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption h1 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-dark">
        <h1 style="background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250,0.5);">Everyday</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-dark">
        <h1 style="background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250,0.5);">Everyday Creativity</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-dark">
        <h1 style="background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250,0.5);">Everyday Creativity, Everyday </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can decrease the `width` of `h1` to its content via `max-content` or `display:table;` for older browsers :

```css
body {background:tomato;}
```

```html
<code>max-content</code><h1 style="background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250,0.5);margin:1em auto;width:max-content;">Everyday Creativity</h1>
<code>display:table;</code><h1 style="background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250,0.5);margin:1em auto;display:table;">Everyday Creativity</h1>
```

infos :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display